# Fitting a model using Polynomial Regression doesn't allow to predict because of the shape issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I wrote below code to use Polynomial regression. Am able to fit the model, but not able to predict!!

```
def polynomial_function(power=5, random_state=9):
    global X_train
    global y_train

    X_train =  X_train[['item_1','item_2','item_3','item_4']]
    rng = np.random.RandomState(random_state)
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=power, include_bias=False)
    linreg = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
    new_X_train = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
    linreg.fit(new_X_train, y_train)
    new_x_test  = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(1, -1)
    print linreg.predict(new_x_test)
    return linreg

linreg = polynomial_function()
```

Am getting below error message:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,4) and (125,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 125 (dim 0)
```

The error happens here,

```
new_x_test  = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(1, -1)
print linreg.predict(new_x_test)
```

I found shape of new_X_train = (923, 125) 
and shape of new_x_test = (1, 4)

How does this matter?

When I try to predict using a shape of (1, 4) does the algorithm try to convert it to a different shape?

Does it try to find out a polynomial of degree of 5 for test data?

I am trying to Learn polynomial regression, can anyone explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=5, include_bias=False)),
    ('linreg', LinearRegression(normalize=True))
    ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipeline.predict(np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(1, -1))
```

Comment: Actually am returning "linreg" after fitting the model. Others call my model using  model=polynomial_function();   model.predict(np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(1, -1)); ,  How can I handle this in my function? Any solution for this?

Comment: Why is `new_x_test` inside your function? And why does your example show you predicting inside your function if your goal was to return the model to then use to predict?

Comment: I put new_x_test for simplicity. I was testing the function. I thought I can apply the solution when "new_x_test" is outside the function. But now I cannot. Can you please suggest a solution if "new_x_test" is coming from outside, like:  model.predict(np.array([4, 5, 6, 7]).reshape(1, -1))

Comment: Why does it gives different different output!! How can we use RandomState() here?